# how to auto scale django project in Elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, continuous-deployment

I have my Django setup on Elastic beanstalk, it's working properly considering on single instance. But when tested with ALB, the auto-scaled instance appears to be missing application code when it gets launched which it should have taken from s3 I assume (I had used console and uploaded my source bundle directly). I want to have source code reflected in autoscaled instance. What am i missing, is there any way for it or to automate this with using AMI image?

Comment: Autoscale instances should have your code automatically, unless you uploaded it manually. How exactly did you setup your project?

Comment: Yes Correct! Code should get reflected and is now, I had done some wrong configuration, is resolved now. Thanks :)